# Unit testing Javascript/JQuery with JSUnit vs Qunit vs XUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

We are using JQuery and some bit of Javascript in our project.
We are thinking of writing some unit test around it for which there are different ways like
JSUnit, Qunit, XUnit

Can anyone suggest which is the best way to unit test javascript/jquery and if possible with some good link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest QUnit. jQuery itself uses it for internal unit testing.

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit#Using_QUnit)

Chad Myers has a good intro [post](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/08/28/getting-started-with-jquery-qunit-for-client-side-javascript-testing.aspx) into using qUnit.